# How to add pause/resume functionality to an application?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing an app, where most of the work is done by background threads (10 - 500 threads).

I'd like to add pause/resume functionality.

Before, you could do that with Thread.Suspend and Thread.Resume. But those functions are considered obsolete now.

Is there anything that would let me do the same with equal ease?

I'm writing the software in c#

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information if you want anything like a useful response. What are these threads doing? How are they started? Under what conditions are they to be "paused?" Without more information, it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: 500 threads in a process is an *enormous* number of threads, particularly if a bunch of them are asleep much of the time. My advice is to redesign your architecture to use no more threads than there are processors in the machine. Threads are very "heavy" in C#; you should be creating the absolute minimum necessary to get the job done. What are you doing that you are creating so many threads?

Comment: This is a web crawling app. Each thread spends most of its time waiting for a response from some web server, all threads are started at the same place, and should be paused when the user presses "pause" button. The app usually takes 700m-2G of memory, and I'm ok with this unless there is a better way to do this; even at 500 threads, the app usually takes less than 30% of a single cpu to run

Comment: You might consider looking into the async CTP that we have released. Judicious use of `DownloadDataTaskAsync` might make your life a lot easier.

Comment: There's that word again; "heavy". Why are things so heavy in the futures? Is there a problem with the frameworks gravitational pull?

Comment: +1 @Eric.  Arsen:  Assuming you're using a recent version of C# and .Net, consider using the Task library.  You don't need a CTP to do it and it'll fit into your code relatively naturally.  If you're using an older version of C# and .Net, schedule work with manual continuations to the thread pool (don't make a thread pool thread sit there waiting for network I/O!)  Per your comment, there is a _much_ better way to do this, as evidenced by the fact that you're scheduling up to 500 threads to do the work of 1 to 4.

Comment: @MartinJames: Please excuse the crudity of the framework; I didn't have time to build it to scale or to paint it.

Comment: @EricLippert - thanks for the Dr. Emmett Gates quote!

Comment: @Martin, you mean Emmett Brown, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having written a high performance crawler in C#, I can say with some authority that explicitly managing dozens or hundreds of threads is not the best way to go. It can be done (I did it), but it's painful in the extreme.

That said . . .

If your application is written the way I think, then each thread does something like this:

```
while (!Shutdown)
{
    // get next url to crawl from somewhere
    // download the data from that url
    // do something with the data
}
```

Pausing the threads between downloads is pretty easy. I would suggest making two `ManualResetEvent` instances: one for continue, and one for shutdown. These are `static` so that all crawler threads can access them:

```
static ManualResetEvent ShutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
static ManualResetEvent ContinueEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
```

Then, each thread uses `WaitAny` in a loop:

```
WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[] { ShutdownEvent, ContinueEvent };
while (true)
{
    int handle = WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles);  // wait for one of the events
    if (handle == -1 || handle >= handles.Length)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException();
    }

    if (handles[handle] = ShutdownEvent)
       break;  // shutdown was signaled

    if (handles[handle] == ContinueEvent)
    {
        // download the next page and do something with the data
    }
}
```

Note that when I defined the `handles` array, I specified `ShutdownEvent` first. The reason is that if multiple items are signaled, `WaitAny` returns the lowest index that corresponds to a signaled object. If the array were populated in the other order, then you wouldn't be able to shut down without pausing first.

Now, if you want the threads to shut down, call `ShutdownEvent.Set`. And if you want the threads to pause, call `ContinueEvent.Reset` When you want the threads to resume, call `ContinueEvent.Set`.

Pausing in the middle of a download is a bit more difficult. It's possible to do, but the problem is that if you pause for too long the server might timeout. And then you'll have to restart the download from the beginning or, if the server and your code support it, restart the download from the point at which you left off. Either option is rather painful, so I wouldn't suggest trying to pause in the middle of a download.

Answer (score 2):

What does your app do?

500 threads is far too many - that's 1/2 GB of committed memory just for the stacks. And then you have all the context switching.

Good that you want to get rid of the `Suspend` and `Resume` calls, but I suggest you have a look at your architecture first - can you move to APM methods ( BeginXXX / EndXXX )?

Comment: Mostly, this is a networking application, which downloads information from the web. Because it spends most of its time waiting for the responses, multithreading it seems like a good idea to me. If you know of a better way to accomplish it, let me know

Answer (score 1):

As a caveat regarding what i'm about to say: It's not clear what your app does; there are many simple methods for using thread pool threads such as TPL, background workers etc.

However, if you have threads that you have created (not threadpool) and you want them to communicate then use Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse with a boolean blocking condition.

e.g:

```
    bool _isPaused;

void DoWork()
{
        while (true)
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                while (_isPaused) Monitor.Wait(_locker);

                // your worker code here

            }

        }
}
        // 
void UnPause()
{
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _isPaused=false;
            Monitor.PulseAll(_locker);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Suspend/Resume are really simple and work fine until they crash your app, eg. by suspending a thread that has the memory manager or file system locked up :(

The usual, slightly more complex, approach is to find somewhere in your threads where you can wait.  In you case, I'm guessing that most of the threads are normally blocked on some IO call anyway and so are 'suspended', so a good place to enforce a 'suspend' is straight after the read in order to catch those threads where the read does return.

You can do the actual suspending by checking a global boolean 'isRunning' flag as suggested by @Andrey and, if a suspend is needed, block on a global ManualResetEvent.  To suspend, clear the event and then the flag.  To resume, set the flag and then the event.

If using globals makes you feel nauseous, you can pass in the ctor a common instance of some class containing the flag, event and 'suspend(), 'resume()' and 'checkForSuspend()' methods.

Rgds,
Martin